# Change State - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I define a state like this,

const [title, changeTitle] = useState('');

So, the value of the variable Title is an empty string.

Then, I receive a JSON, form :{active: '1', name: 'New Form', …}

I need to change the state title to New Form.
changeTitle(form.name);

But then, the variable Title is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post you code and full json

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post to format your code using the editor tools. Also, revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: I think what you're doing is fine, but you just need to ensure that `form.name` is defined when you call `changeTitle(form.name);`. To help you understand what is going wrong, we need more informations about your code.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that when you call `changeTitle` the variable `form.name` is not undefined.
If you are using react hooks and the variable `form` is a state or prop you can use a `useEffect` and change the state of title only when the variable `form.name` is defined

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(form.name){
  changeTitle(form.name);
 }
},[form.name]);
```

Comment: i think you meant `changeTitle(form.name);`

Comment: Yes you are right. I edited the answer :)

Comment: the form.name have a value, 100% sure. And if I put a string, for example, changetTitle('123') instead of form.name the value of the variable title is correct. And  the value of the form.name is a string too.

Comment: Make sure that the json has been parsed correctly like this const obj = JSON.parse(form);

If also this one is not your case post your code so I can give you a more precise solution